# why is $stmt -> num_rows returning 0 when login exists?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-num-rows

Making a login form and this is my first time using prepared statements. My issue is the num_rows keeps returning 0, despite entering the correct email and password that matches the email and password of my table. I tested that the connection works and the SQL statement works also, its just the num_rows is always 0.

PHP(without php tags and connection code):

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `email`, `password` FROM users WHERE `email` = ? AND  `password` = ?")))
    {
       echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ")" . $con->error;
    }
    else
    {
       echo " Query read \n";

       $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->store_result();
       $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
       $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);

       echo $num_of_rows;

        if($num_of_rows == 1) //To check if the row exists
        {
            echo "Exists";

               if($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
               {
                  echo "Exists";
                  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                  $_SESSION['message'] = "logged in";
                  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                  echo "Success!";
                  exit();
               }
        }

        else 
        {
           echo "Error";
        }
     }
```

Hopefully I've just forgotten something, but either way I am stumped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should hash your passwords better than a simple MD5. Look up salted hashes. Use a complex salt and possibly multiple hash types, just to be safe.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks. :)

Comment: Why do you need to fetch the results? If the query finds any rows, the values are guaranteed to be the same as the input variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned ditch out, my_num_rows, and store_result, below works for me.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$arr = array();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM users where email = :email 
and password = :password");
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $password);
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);

$stmt->execute();
$arr = $stmt->fetchAll();
if(!$arr) exit('No rows');
print_r($arr);
$stmt = null;
```

Comment: Had to change a few things but works. Thank you so much.

Comment: The code in this answer looks like **PDO**. OP code looks like its using **mysqli**. Does this answer address the question that was asked? "*Why is num_rows returning 0?*"

Answer (score 4):

The value returned by `num_rows` may not be a valid count of rows returned until all of the rows are retrieved. That's the case for a `mysqli_result`. The documentation makes it appear that the `num_rows` function of a `mysqli_stmt` should be available immediately after a `store_result`.

Seems like the most reasonable explanation for the behavior is that the query did not return a row.

Documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

---

Why do we need to use `num_rows` at all? That just seems like a lot of unneeded clutter. We could just do the fetch. If it returns TRUE, we know there was at least one row returned. If it's FALSE, then zero rows were returned. No need to muck with `num_rows`.

If we are going to use `store_result`, its a good pattern to follow that with a `free_result` once we're done with the resultset

---

Also, do not use MD5 for password hash. And there's no need to return the password hash from the database, we can omit that from the SELECT list.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

---

Comment: So what would you suggest to fix this?

Comment: I suggest ditching the `store_result`, and the `num_rows`. Just do the prepare, bind, execute, and fetch. As a first step in debugging, I'd neuter the password check.  Just modify the SQL so it doesn't matter if the password matches ... `WHERE u.email = ? AND ( u.password = ? OR 1=1 )`  and see if we get a row back.  If that's not returning a row, then I'd test with a hardcoded email, ignore the value being passed in the $_POST and see if we get a row back. I suggest figuring out exactly  where the problem is. Once we diagnose it, ie know what and where the problem is, then we can fix it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the problem is that `$_POST('email')` and/or `$_POST('password')` aren't returning the values we are expecting to be returned. A couple of echo or vardump would be a quick and dirty way to add some debugging, so we can see what is being returned.

Comment: I put lots of var_dumps and echos for email and password, and it recognizes the input. When I do var_dump($stmt_fetch()), it says NULL. Maybe its not binding the result? Or binding param is not working? Or could html be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You also want to fetch the results, like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->store_result();
       $stmt->fetch();
       $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
       $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
       echo $num_of_rows;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this still gives me 0. :(

Comment: Why would calling `fetch()` change the value of `$num_of_rows`? The variable was set before you called it.